# Cannot find csv data file where progress is saved (Python/Pyinstaller base, possibly sys. MEIPASS or NSIS ?)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sys

Qualifier quite new to Python.
I wrote some Python code importing pandas, selenium, sys, os, tkinter, and pillow, then put together with pyinstaller and NSIS.
The programme uses a csv file for its input and updates this based on user actions. The updates are to be saved internally so if the user quits they can continue where they left off.
It all saves properly, user progress saves and picks up correctly, and if I "download CSV" the file is up-to-date. It all works perfectly, functionally speaking.

However, when the programme is run, the csv that it starts with is not where it is saving the progress. It stays the same. The "progress" data is being saved somewhere else From a data security perspective, I need to know where it is saving. I could not find it after hours of looking.

Even if I uninstall the programme and reinstall, it still remembers the progress. Tested also on machines with no Python etc.

I am using:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    CurrentPath = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    CurrentPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Could that be it?
The save line itself is rather standard:

`df.to_csv('file_s.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

My only other idea is it relates to NSIS installer and the uninstall script. There are painfully few tutorials for beginners on that. If the community thinks that is the issue, I think it best I post a new question with relevant info.

Apologies if this is too vague and happy to provide anymore needed info!

Comment: NSIS does not automatically uninstall for you, it is all manual instructions in its script. I don't see how the NSIS tag is relevant here.

Comment: Edited "feature" to "script" and removed tag. Hope you feel better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the `CurrentPath` variable using the standard "if frozen" approach, which looks OK. But, you don't then seem to use it when you save the file.

Try explicitly concatenating it with the filename to save

`df.to_csv(os.path.join(CurrentPath,'file_s.csv'),encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

Note that when you run as a executable, `sys._MEIPASS` will be a temporary folder created (on Windows atleast) somewhere like `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\Temp\MEIXXX`

Comment: Thanks! That could be it. I tested it and it did work. However, it still draws on that "hidden" file (i.e. remembers my old progress). I need to try this on a system I did not mess up and then can mark this as answered. Definitely puts me on the right direction. Appreciate your time, I've focused on learning back end data science the past months, but somebody wanted my application so was time to learn new things.

Comment: Your code sample was for writing to the CSV output. Are you also using this approach when reading the input file? A bit of a hacky trick could be to just print (or log) the name of the file prior to reading/writing it. Then you could absolutely see where it was coming from and it might give you a hint.

`csv_write = os.path.join(CurrentPath,"file.csv")
print(csv_write) # or log.debug(csv_write) if using logging
df.to_csv(csv_write, encoding="utf-8", index=False)`

It should give you some clues.

Comment: Just to elaborate a tad how I know this may be right: when I install the updated programme with your changes in a different directory (e.g. desktop) instead of the program folder (where I installed my old broken programme), it works perfectly... the csv I expect to be updated is updated. Also if I uninstall the programme and reinstall it does not "remember" progress from previous install. Will test on other machines asap.

Comment: Yep, I updated the reading of the input file also per your advice. Will try your hacky trick soon as I can. Will also change all the file names etc. then test again in Programs, time consuming but should confirm your fix functions when it does not conflict with something I previously broke.

Comment: Marked this as the answer since I have received no complaints about the problem reappearing. Thanks again (and apologies it took so long).